# "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: asp.net, membership

I saw many questions on SO with this error. But none were related to forms. I just hosted my application server after testing locally. I think it worked for a few mins but I'm not sure as I may have looked at the localhost tab for a moment. Then it stopped working. I may have changed something as I was making changes on server too.

I checked my connection string and also tried logging into the DB using other ways and it is online. So, any clues what could be wrong. I don't think it is possible that sql server is only not responding to requests from an app and is available if you log in through SSMS.

Below is the error I get.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5296071    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308555
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +145
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +920
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions) +434
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +558
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +67
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +83    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +79
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +384
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +241
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +26
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +170
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.GetStorageMetadata(String
>   providerName, DbConnection connection, String ssdl) +35
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMetadataWorkspace(String
>   providerName, DbConnection connection, String csdl, String ssdl,
>   String msl) +154
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateEntityConnection(ConnectionStringSettings
>   setting, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +109
>   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings
>   setting) +28
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String
>   userName, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String&
>   password, Int32& format, String& salt, Int32&
>   failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
>   Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime&
>   lastActivityDate) +118
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String
>   userName, String password, Boolean updateLastActivityDate, Boolean
>   failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +81
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
>   username, String password) +105
>   System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String
>   password) +26    Staff.Web.Account.Login.OnAuthenticate(Object sender,
>   AuthenticateEventArgs e) in
>   c:\Assembla\SVN\servicesdue\Staff.Web\Staff.Web\Account\Login.aspx.cs:28
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs
>   e) +9449786    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +119
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs
>   e) +75    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +159
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055

Someone also had this error and they said they were using the wrong store to connect to DB and hence the error. I only have one store in my code. There is no other.

Update:

I found the problem. It is membership related. Something is not right with my membership connection string. But I don't know what. My app requires registration so authentication is enabled. I left the default settings alone. Also published the mdf file in the App_Data folder. 
There is a similar question here: [Deploying ASP.NET membership to Godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974117/deploying-asp-net-membership-to-godaddy?rq=1). But the solution is not clear and the answer is marked. I added the 
    
to the connection string and I see the error

> The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications
>   configuration or the connection string is empty.

So, what should I do? This membership is working flawlessly locally.

Update:

I also tried what this one suggests [Godaddy ASP.NET membership database woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746068/godaddy-asp-net-membership-database-woes). I removed the conn string and added with the name "LocalSqlServer" to make Godaddy happy. Then I removed and added the following with this connectionStringName - DefaultProfileProvider, DefaultMembershipProvider, DefaultRoleProvider and DefaultSessionProvider. Still get the same error of system cannot find the specified file.

Comment: What's in your 'defaultConnectionFactory' in web.config? I also have maybe the same issue, and I believe it related to defaultConnectionFactory

Comment: I ran into several issues and resolved all. Not sure what it was but it was nothing related to defaultConnectionFactory. I think this error was where I had TrustedConnection=true in the config.

Comment: I had this error and I found that the name of one of my connection strings was wrong. Check the names as well as the actual string.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. text**

Generally issues like this are related to any of the following need to be looked at:

- firewall settings from the web server to the database server
- connection string errors
- enable the appropriate protocol pipes/ tcp-ip

Try connecting to sql server with sql management server on the system that sql server is installed on and work from there. Pay attention to information in the errorlogs.

Comment: It seems I cannot use the .mdf file on production server. SQL server needs to be configured for membership. I guess that's the problem.

Comment: Marked this as answer as this is very close to the actual issue I had.

Comment: @strider we are having a similar issue ? What was the issue on your case ?

Comment: Like I mentioned above in comment above question, I was having multiple issues and do not exactly remember how I resolved this one. But I think this error was where I had TrustedConnection=true in the config and I was using credentials to log in. Hope it helps.

Comment: For me... it was a "fat fingered" connection string.  I put in an extra character in the server name... (headbang)

Comment: I had this problem too. My "SQLSERVERAGENT" service had been stopped. When I started this service my problem was solved.

Comment: My problem is the same with @MajidBasirati. Now I fixed with [How to start with sql server agent](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191454%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and set it to automatic instead of manual.

Answer (score 10):

I got same error after publish my project to my physical server. My web application works perfectly on my computer when I compile on `VS2013`. When I checked connection string on sql server manager, everything works perfect on server too. I also checked firewall (I switched it off). But still didn't work. I remotely try to connect database by SQL Manager with exactly same user/pass and instance name etc with protocol pipe/tcp and I saw that everything working normally. But when I try to open website I'm getting this error. Is there anyone know 4th option for fix this problem?.

NOTE: My App: `ASP.NET 4.5 (by VS2013)`, Server: `Windows 2008 R2 64bit`, SQL: `MS-SQL WEB 2012 SP1` 
Also other web applications works great at web browsers with their database on same server.

---

**After one day suffering I found the solution of my issue:**

First I checked all the logs and other details but i could find nothing. Suddenly I recognize that; when I try to use connection string which is connecting directly to published DB and run application on my computer by VS2013, I saw that it's connecting another database file. I checked local directories and I found it. ASP.NET Identity not using my connection string as I wrote in web.config file. And because of this VS2013 is creating or connecting a new database with the name "DefaultConnection.mdf" in App_Data folder. Then I found the solution, it was in *IdentityModel.cs*.

I changed code as this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") ---> this was original
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("<myConnectionStringNameInWebConfigFile>") //--> changed
    {
    }
}
```

So, after all, I re-builded and published my project and everything works fine now :)

Comment: And how exactly did you obtain the alternative connection string? Is it accessible from Azure portal somehow? Where?

Comment: I've been getting this error intermittently with my published application. I checked the ApplicationDbContext and it was incorrect. I made the proper changes and it came right up. Again, it was intermittent (I would have assumed it would have been consistant with such an error), but hopefully I don't get this error again.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter this error in GoDaddy after deploying a .Net MVC web application..And your web.config is absolutely correct... Right click your data project select settings and make sure that the correct connection strings to the GoDaddy server is in use

Answer (score 2):

start the sql server agent, that should fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - for me it was the SQL Server running out of memory. Freeing up some memory solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason could be the database connection string. You have to change the connection string attachDBFile=|DataDirectory|file_name.mdf.
there might be problem in host name which would be (local),localhost or .\sqlexpress.

Answer (score 0):

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
>      {
>                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblemployee",con);
>                    con.Open();
>                    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>                    GridView1.DataBind();
> ```
>
> Source File: d:\C#
>   programs\kudvenkat\adobasics1\adobasics1\employeedata.aspx.cs    Line:
>   23

**if your error is same like mine..just do this**

right click on your table in sqlserver object explorer,choose properties
in lower left corner in general option there is a connection block with server and connection specification.in your web config for datasource=. or local choose name specified in server in properties..

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when starting my ASP.NET application and in my case the problem was that the SQL Server service was not running. Starting that cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that a ***LocalDb*** instance only intended for use in development. ***LocalDb*** is not available for production servers When you deploy the final result.

**I think your connection string is pointing to a *LocalDb* instance and you need to take certain steps to turn it into the SQL Server database.** It's not just a matter of copying an *mdf* file either. It will possibly differ from one hosting company to another, but typically, you need to create a backup of your existing database (a .bak file) and then restore that to the hosting company's SQL Server. You should ask them where you can find instructions on deploying your database into production.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error while connecting to the local database. In my case it worked after starting service in Services: SQL server (*INSTANCE_NAME*)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering this error in Visual Studio or similar thhi2 please read this paragraph:

Please add these 2 pieces of code to the file (here I will call the 2 initial files when creating the project MainProject) MainProject.cpp:

```
#include "MainForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    FirstCppProject::MainForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
    return 0;
}
```

and MainProject.h (GUI code file)

```
#pragma once

namespace FirstCppProject {
    public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
    public:
        MainForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private:
        System::Void InitializeComponent() {
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // Initialize other components here
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
        }
    };
}
```

Then save and run the program again (Build -> Build Solution)

I will take my own answer in another post because both of these problems can be solved in the same way.