# Connection String error while changing database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I developed my web application using Asp.net and SQL Server. After that I try to host it on my local server. I installed SQL Server Express on my server and created the database on that server. And then I host my web app after changing my connection string according to the new database. But I get an error while running the web site. I use Windows authentication in SQL Server. Please help me fix this issue.

> The system cannot find the file specified
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>   The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode.

To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error.

   Example:

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
   ```

or:

2. Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

   ```
   <configuration>
       <system.web>
           <compilation debug="true"/>
       </system.web>
   </configuration>
   ```

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463119/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified

Comment: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Evaluation" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Comment: can you please post your connection string?

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection"
      connectionString="Data Source=GISSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Evaluation;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>